# Terraform, docker, Debian 8

Tags: docker, ssh, configuration, debian, terraform

I am beginner with Terraform and I looking for help. I tried use google, but I can not find solutions for me.

I have Debian 8 server. I installed docker and terraform succesfully. Now I need create docker container with ubuntu and set up ssh access to this container with Terraform. My terraform config is for create docker container, set image and provider to docker, but I can not find how to set ssh access to it or configure some addition SW.

Terraform config:

```
# Configure the Docker provider
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376/"
}

# Definition of ubuntu image
resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu:latest"
}

# Create a container
resource "docker_container" "Ubn_Con" {
  image = "${docker_image.ubuntu.latest}"
  name  = "Ubn_Con"
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you want Terraform to install software inside your container? Why not do that in a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) instead?

Comment: Thank you for advice. How I said I am beginner and I try find a way for my solution. Dockerfile seems to be good way.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker_container` resource has an attribute called `network_data`, which has `ip_address`. That is the IP address of your container, so you could use that with SSH.

However, Jan Mesarc is correct, you do not need to SSH into a container to set it up with software (or ever, actually, but that's a longer story). Instead, you create an image for the container to be brought up from, using a Dockerfile.

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl
```

Then you build that image with `docker build . -t ubuntu-curl:0.0.1`, and upload it to Dockerhub. If you want to use another registry, just change the value to `-t` to include the full URL.

Then you can use that image in your `docker_image` resource:

```
resource "docker_image" "ubuntu" {
  name = "ubuntu-curl:0.0.1"
}
```